# How to estimate beta distribution parameters using a beta binomial with empirical bayes

Tags: beta-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution, empirical-bayes

I would like to estimate parameters for a beta distribution using a maximum likelihood approach in python (as mentioned [here](http://varianceexplained.org/r/empirical_bayes_baseball/)). I can do this for a beta:

```
from scipy.stats import beta

beta.fit(beta.rvs(a=70, b=250, loc=0, size=100), floc=0, fscale=1)
```

(74.75869456937754, 263.8103868963194, 0, 1)

If I then try to optimise parameters with respect to beta binomial likelihood I get the parameters tending towards infinity (although with the correct mean).

```
from scipy.stats import betabinom
from scipy.optimize import fmin

def beta_bin_nll(param, *args):
    a, b = param
    
    data = args[0]
    total_nll = 0
    for datum in data:
        logpmf = betabinom.logpmf(k=datum[0],n=datum[1],a=a,b=b)
        total_nll -= logpmf
        
    return total_nll

data = [[round(r), 100] for r in beta.rvs(a=70, b=250, loc=0, scale=100, size=100)]
fmin(beta_bin_nll, [1, 1], args=(data,))
```

Optimization terminated successfully.
Current function value: 245.060220
Iterations: 164
Function evaluations: 360
array([4.72558414e+07, 1.72507488e+08])

How can I get this to correctly predict my beta parameters?

---

The problem is that I'm generating data using a beta distribution, if I use a beta binomial the fit works fine:

```
from scipy.stats import beta
data = [[round(r), 100] for r in betabinom.rvs(100, 70, 250, loc=0, size=1000, random_state=None)]
fmin(beta_bin_nll, [1, 1], args=(data,))
```

Comment: Two points about your code are confusing to me. First, why are you rounding the beta draws to be integers? Second, if you're drawing from a beta distribution, why do you end up fitting an MLE for a beta-binomial distribution? If there is some more context around this, it might be useful to share.

Comment: I've tidied up the code so that it's more understandable. I'm trying to follow [this](http://varianceexplained.org/r/empirical_bayes_baseball/) example, but I can't understand how to use the beta-binomial he mentions in the apendix